# global variable PHP not getting updated

Tags: php

In my code:

```
<?php

$var1 = 0; //I want `$var1` to retain its value in all functions `abc()` and `xyz()`

abc();

function abc()
{
    global $var1;
    $varDatabase = 10; //a value from database
    $var1 = &$varDatabase; //$var1 set as reference

    xyz(); //$var1 is changed in xyz() function

    echo $var1; //I expect value 110 here but it return last value 10
}

function xyz()
{
    global $var1;
    $var1 = $var1 + 100;
}

?>
```

My variable `$var1` is set as a pointer/reference to another variable `$varDatabase`. `$var1` is updated in a function `xyz()`, and I expect its new updated value in calling function after `xyz()` is executed. That is why I have set `$var1` as `global`, but still it does not give me updated value after `xyz()` is executed.

All I want is`$var1` to retain its value in all functions `abc()` and `xyz()`

Comment: You don't need the `global` statement outside the function.

Comment: ok. but still I want updated value. How do I get it?

Comment: I know what you want, it's clear from the question. If I knew the answer I would post it.

Comment: I think you are referencing a local variable `$varDatabase`, so `$var1` also become local scoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables are implemented by making the variable a reference to the corresponding `$GLOBALS` element, i.e.

```
global $var1;
```

is equivalent to

```
$var1 = &GLOBALS['var1'];
```

But if you then redefine it to be a reference to some other variable, it's no longer a reference to the `$GLOBALS` element, so it's not a global variable any more.

See the documentation [References with *global* and *static* variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references)

If you want `$var1` to retain its value, make it a global variable, but don't make it a reference to `$varDatabase`. Just do

```
$var1 = $varDatabase;
```

Comment: the right answer is to tell OP that he can pass variables as function arguments, so he can stop doing this mess with globals

Comment: That would be a great comment, but it's not an answer. There are appropriate uses for global variables.

Comment: I know, I can pass variables, but there are like 20 variables getting set with different values at different point of code in more than 10 functions, so, it will make a lot of mess to change all functions. After removing "&" code is working fine. Thanks. Sometimes, its best to have a quick fix instead of going for perfect solution because there is a time constraint in the project.

Comment: @user2891329 If you have so many parameters, you could put them into an array or class instead of lots of different variables.